# How to save one-to-many relationship after insert in a transaction

Tags: javascript, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am using Bookshelf v0.10.3 with Knex v0.12.9, in an Express v4.15.2 server on Node v6.9.5.

I have a `user` table with an associated `identity` table, joined by an `identity_user` table. The tables are created using Knex:

```
Promise.all([
  knex.schema.createTable('user', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('username');
    table.string('password');
    table.unique('username');
  }),
  knex.schema.createTable('identity', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('type');
    table.string('value');
  }),
  knex.schema.createTable('identity_user', table => {
    table.integer('user_id').references('user.id');
    table.integer('identity_id').references('identity.id');
    table.unique(['user_id', 'identity_id']);
  })
]);
```

My Bookshelf models look like this:

```
bookshelf.plugin([ 'registry', 'bookshelf-camelcase' ]);

const Identity = bookshelf.model('Identity', {
  tableName: 'identity',

  user() {
    return this.belongsTo('User', 'identity_user');
  }
});

const User = bookshelf.model('User', {
  tableName: 'user',

  initialize() {
    this.on('saving', model => {
      if (model.hasChanged('username')) {
        return model.set('username', String(model.attributes.username).toLowerCase());
      }
    });
    this.on('saving', model => {
      if (model.hasChanged('password')) {
        return bcrypt.hash(model.attributes.password, 10)
          .then(hash => model.set('password', hash));
      }
    });
  },

  identities() {
    return this.hasMany('Identity', 'identity_user');
  }
});
```

In my `createUser` function, I'm trying to insert a new user and an identity in a single transaction.

```
function createUser(req, res, next) {
  const { email, username, password } = req.body;

  // some data validation

  return bookshelf.transaction((t) => {
    return new User({ username, password } ).save(null, { transacting: t })
      .then(user => new Identity({ type: 'email', value: email }).save({ userId: user.attributes.id }, { transacting: t }))
      .then(() => res.sendStatus(204))
      .catch(err => {
        // handle PostgreSQL unique violation error
      });
  });
}
```

When I run the server and attempt to register a new user, I get the following error:

```
insert into "identity" ("type", "user_id", "value") values ($1, $2, $3) returning "id" - column "user_id" of relation "identity" does not exist { error: insert into "identity" ("type", "user_id", "value") values ($1, $2, $3) returning "id" - column "user_id" of relation "identity" does not exist
```

This is a PostgreSQL error (code 42703 - Undefined Column), but everything seems to be set up correctly. I could really use another set of eyes on this. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was because Bookshelf found 'userId' being inserted into **Identity** and inferred the column name to be 'user_id'. But for connecting to MxN relationships you need to use [`attach()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-attach) instead:

```
function createUser(req, res, next) {
  const { email, username, password } = req.body;

  // some data validation

  return bookshelf.transaction((t) => {
    return new User({ username, password } )
      .save(null, { transacting: t })
      .then(user => new Identity({ type: 'email', value: email })
        .save(null, { transacting: t }))
      .then(identity => user.identities()
        .attach(identity.id, { transacting: t }));
  })
  .then(() => res.sendStatus(204))
  .catch(err => {
    // handle PostgreSQL unique violation error
  });
}
```

A variation that also seems to work for me is to directly attach models (e.g. `.attach(identity, { transacting: t })`), but this approach is not supported by the documentation.

**Edit** I've overlooked two errors on your model definitions, `hasMany()` only maps to a MxN relationship if using a `through()` call, that requires the join table to be mapped as a model. In the case above I think it is enough to use a simple 'belongsToMany()` call. So replace your relationship definitions by:

```
user() {
  return this.belongsToMany('User');
}
```

and

```
identities() {
  return this.belongsToMany('Identity');
}
```

**Edit2**: Moved the `catch()` to outside of the transaction scope, so an exception will automatically trigger a rollback.

**Edit3**: Flatter `then()` chain and non-db stuff removed from transaction scope.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, but got: "TypeError: user.identities(...).attach is not a function". Even more perplexing was the fact that the user and identity were both created, despite the relation NOT being added to the linking table. Do I have to manually rollback changes in the catch?

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked two errors on your model definitions.

Comment: If an exception is not caught within the transaction scope `bookshelf.transaction(t=>{<here is the scope>})` then the transaction is automatically rolled back. But if it is caught (and not re-thrown), then the commit will automatically be triggered by bookshelf,

Comment: Awesome thanks! Will try your suggestions later this evening after work and let you know how it goes. Appreciate your help.

Comment: This works, thank you. It's a drag that `hasMany` and `belongsTo` do not behave as expected and the Bookshelf docs are a little fuzzy on 1:n relationships, but otherwise I'm digging this ORM.

Comment: Also worth noting: You don't need to nest the promises like that. The second `then` can be chained off of the first `then` (apposed to the second `save` call). Using Bluebird, I was able to do both inserts in parallel, then `spread` and attach the identity to the user.

Comment: Yes, normally I try to build flat `then()` chains (updating my sample code now...). Another thing I use to do is removing non-db related stuff from the transactions, so lowering the time db resources are blocked.